# What do we exactly mean by charge and why the elementary charge of electron is $1.602176634×10^{−19} C$?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge, si-units, metrology

A coulomb is 6.241 x 10^18 elementary charges. But what exactly is a **coulomb**? And what do we mean exactly by a **charge**? how was it measured?
[image]

Comment: It might be good to try looking it up, wikipedia is a good place to start.

Comment: It is a requirement on Physics SE that people do basic background research to find an answer.  An answer to "what do we mean exactly by a charge ?" would really involve a deep dive into the equally deep complexities of Quantum Electrodynamics  The rest of it is described on Wikipedia and many other sites.  I'd suggest [Wikipedia's page on Electric Charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge) as a reasonable point to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we say "charge" we mean an attribute that measures the strength of the interaction between an object and the electromagnetic field. Charge is, as far as we know, an unchangeable and intrinsic property of certain elementary particles such as the electron and the quark, (which is a constituent of protons and neutrons). It is a conserved property, which means that the net charge (total positive charge minus total negative charge) of an isolated system never changes.

A coulomb is the standard unit of charge in the International System of Units (often called SI units). It is defined as the quantity of electric charge carried in one second by a current of one ampere. Since 2019, the ampere is in turn defined so that charge on an electron or on a proton (known as the *elementary charge*) is exactly $1.602176634 \times 10^{−19}$ coulombs.

There are various methods for measuring the charge on an electron with a very high degree of precision. One of them is [Millikan's oild drop experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment).